# Query to retrieve records by aplhabetic order, except for n predefined items which must be on top

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need to retrieve all records ordered alphabetically. **Except** for a predefined list of record's columns which their records should appear first in a given predefined order, then all other records should be sorted alphabetically based on the same column

For instance, assume we have the following table which is called `Names`

[image]

Lets assume the predefined list is `("Mathew", "Ashraf", "Jack")`. 
I.e. these are the names  of whom their records should be listed first as in the predefined order.

So the desired query result should be:

[image]

Which query could retrieve this custom order ?

P.S, I'm using MySQL.

---

Here's my trial based on comments' request:

```
(SELECT * FROM Names WHERE Name in ('Mathew', 'Ashraf', 'Jack')) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM Names WHERE Name NOT IN ('Mathew', 'Ashraf', 'Jack') ORDER BY Name ASC);
```

the first query result wasn't ordered as required.

[image]

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD() or ORDER BY name IN (x,y,z) [DESC]

Comment: This will not exclude a list of predefined records from being sorted

Comment: Yes. You don't want to exclude any - as demonstrated by your result set

Comment: Did you try with `UNION` ?

Comment: @strawberry Kindly notice that : Mathew, Ashraf, Jack .. are not ordered like other records

Comment: You can do this with a UNION:  Query1 retrieves the predefined order rows, UNION Query2 retrieve the alphabetized rows.

Comment: Justin lurman, Union was my first trial, but I didn't manage in the second query to exclude some records based on specific field value, and also I didn't manage to display the records in the first query based on a given order as stated in the list

Comment: Can you post your attempted UNION query that didn't work?

Comment: @AshrafBashir I have noticed that. My answer (using FIELD()) is correct.

Comment: @TabAlleman, updated with my union try

Comment: You need to order by something, you can make your query work by: `select id, name from ( (SELECT id, name, 1 as origin FROM Names WHERE Name in ('Mathew', 'Ashraf', 'Jack')) 
UNION 
(SELECT id, name, 2 as origin FROM Names WHERE Name NOT IN ('Mathew', 'Ashraf', 'Jack')) ) as T order by origin, name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES
 ('Sam'),
 ('John'),
 ('Samanta'),
 ('Johny'),
 ('Ashraf'),
 ('Tom'),
 ('Jack'),
 ('Mathew'),
 ('Hans'),
 ('Adam');


 SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY FIELD(name,'Jack','Ashraf','Mathew') DESC,name;
 +----+---------+
 | id | name    |
 +----+---------+
 |  8 | Mathew  |
 |  5 | Ashraf  |
 |  7 | Jack    |
 | 10 | Adam    |
 |  9 | Hans    |
 |  2 | John    |
 |  4 | Johny   |
 |  1 | Sam     |
 |  3 | Samanta |
 |  6 | Tom     |
 +----+---------+
```

You can even use FIND_IN_SET for this...

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(name,'Jack,Ashraf,Mathew') DESC,name;
```

Comment: Honestly, I cannot get it. But it works ! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ashraf, FIELD is a function that maps it's first argument to it's position among the rest of the arguments, and 0 if not found. This is a shorter version of: `case name when 'Jack' then 1 when 'Ashraf' then 2 when 'Mathew' then 3 else 0 end`

Answer (score 2):

If you want Mathew, Ashraf and Jack ordered internally you can use something like:

```
select id, name, case name when 'Mathew' then 1
                           when 'Ashraf' then 2
                           when 'Jack'   then 3
                           else 4
                 end as x
from T
order by x, name
```

if it doesn't matter who of these that gets sorted first:

```
select id, name, case when name in ('Mathew', 'Ashraf', 'Jack') 
                      then 0 else 1 
                 end as x
from T
order by x, name
```